# Object in Realm List is not updated

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

I have a model that holds a List of `MyGroup`.

```
fileprivate let groups: List<MyGroup>
```

`MyGroup` inherits from Realm's `Object`. It has a computed property `percentage` and a property `oldPercentage` which is used to store the last computed property. I do not want to save this to the database so I ignore it.

```
class MyGroup: Object {
    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["oldPercentage"]
    }

    dynamic var oldPercentage: Double = 0

    var percentage: Double {
        //does some basic calculations
    }

    dynamic var name: String = ""
}
```

The problem lies in the code snippet below.

```
do {
    let group = groups[indexPath.row]
    //group.percentage = 0.5, group.name = "Hi"
    try realm.write {
        group.oldPercentage = group.percentage
        print(group.oldPercentage) //prints 0.5
        print(groups[indexPath.row].oldPercentage) //prints 0.0

        groups[indexPath.row].oldPercentage = group.percentage
        print(groups[indexPath.row].oldPercentage) //prints 0.0

        groups[indexPath.row] = group
        print(groups[indexPath.row].oldPercentage) //prints 0.0

        group.name = "Test"
        print(groups[indexPath.row].name) //prints "Test"
    }
catch { ... }
```

I basically want to get the `group`, change the `oldPercentage` property and pass it back to my `UICollectionView`.

I am getting the `group` that was selected by an `indexPath`. This works fine and gives me the correct `group`. Then, I want to change the value of `oldPercentage` to `percentage`. When I do it on the local variable `group`, it changes its value correctly. However, the object in the `groups` list is **not** updated.

I also tried to change the group's `oldPercentage` value without creating a local variable. I did not expect a different behavior than the code above and there wasn't.

My last attempt was to assign the `group` object that successfully printed the correct `oldPercentage` to groups at the `indexPath`. It did not work either.

When working with the `name` property that is saved in the database, the object behaves as expected and the value is updated correctly.

What do I have to do to update my `group` in the `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties ignored by Realm are specific to each object instance, and indexing a `List` returns a new object each time. You will need to either not ignore `oldPercentage` or pass the instance that you set `oldPercentage` on directly to the thing which needs to read it.

Comment: That is what I also found out but I did not know if I did something wrong. I could not find anything in the Realm doc. Thank you, I've already had a workaround but it does not seem as nice as the solution I was aiming for :)